# ETL Pentaho advice (or SQL advice) on convertin CSV into this table format

Tags: sql, etl, pentaho, data-integration

I have a CSV to convert. Transforming the data into my schema is a bit problematic.
I have a locationID in my end table, and in the CSV, there are 1's or a NULL in about 10 columns(each one is a different location).

My logic is: If column("locationThree") == 1, then set locationID to 5 (for example)

I can't figure out how to do this in SQL, is there a tool for this in Pentaho, or how could I do this in SQL?

E.G

```
INSERT INTO endTable(locationID)
SELECT * FROM grubbyCSVData
if(locationOne == "1")
 locationID = 5;
if(locationTwo == "1")
 locationID = 6;
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so the locationID is relative to each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to try combining the [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349) and [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expressions in SQL. Assuming you are using SQL Server something like the following might work. I have not verified that this executes correctly as I've just written it in the browser.

```
INSERT INTO endTable(locationID)
SELECT COALESCE( CASE locationOne
                 WHEN 1 THEN 5
                 ELSE NULL
                 END,
                 CASE locationTwo
                 WHEN 1 THEN 6
                 ELSE NULL
                 END
                );
```

Alternatively you might want to look into the [`PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) statements which are available in SQL Server 2005 onwards.